# Simple Aggregation/ joining of tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables say, A and B of account_numbers. B being a subset of A. How do I join the two tables such that I add an additional field in the output table with the common elements (here account_numbers) being flagged as 1 and rest 0

```
Table A
Account_Number
11
13
15
16
17
20

Table B
Account_Number
13
16
20

Output Table    
Account Flag
11  0
13  1
15  0
16  1
17  0
20  1
```

Comment: Have you tried anything or are you expecting others to write code for you?

Comment: what database platform?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between inner and outer join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-join)

Comment: Sybase @OldProgrammer

Comment: Aleks G, I am pretty much new to SQL. Hence the ask. When I did a left join to have all the elements included according to the requirements of the output table, I am not sure how to add a field where I can flag the common elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT account_number, COUNT(*)-1 AS flag
FROM (
  SELECT account_number FROM A
    UNION ALL
  SELECT account_number FROM B
) AB
GROUP BY account_number;
```

Checkout [**this demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c01b33/7). Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Exactly how I wanted the table to look like.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to approach this is with a `left outer join`:

```
select a.account_number,
       (case when b.account_number is null then 0 else 1 end) as flag
from A left outer join
     B
     on A.account_number = b.account_number;
```

Comment: Gordon this too works fine. Helped in clarifying some doubts. Thank you and Yang both for your help.

Comment: @Yang's solution is quite clever.  On the other hand, this will generally make better use of indexes, be faster, retains duplicates in table A, and allows you to easily include more columns from with `A` or `B`.

Comment: Yes, I too had this question; if there were more columns probably count(*)-1 won't work. But then Yang's was extremely clever and was precise to my query. Thanks again @Gordon

Answer (score 2):

Try an outer join instead of group by and union all, it will perform much bettter, particularly with large tables.

```
select a.account_number
  , case 
      when b.account_number is not null then 1
      else 0
    end as flag
from a, b
where a.account_number *= b.account_number
```

Comment: Yes, Gordon too gave this solution. Valuable tips on optimisation. Thanks.